# Getting Unique System ID on Mac using C#(Mono)

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, hardware-id

Im porting a windows application for Mac using Mono.I cannot use DPAPI in Mac and i think there is restriction in getting Mainboard/CPU id in Mac for User Level programs.So is there something like DPAPI in windows which i can use using Mono to get a unique system id that does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, stay away from using a MAC address as those can change (spoofed or hardware change) and is not a very Mac'ie way since 10.3/4?... Since then the "I/O Kit registry" is the preferred method to get a system id. Drop to a cmd line and `man ioreg` for same details.

So, not sure if you are using Xamarin.Mac or not, so if you *are* you could do a binding of the IOKit IORegistryEntryFromPath/IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty APIs as I do not believe those are currently in C# wrappers, but really quick way that I use is:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace uuidmac
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static string MacUUID ()
        {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo () {
                FileName = "sh",
                Arguments = "-c \"ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/'\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UserName = Environment.UserName
            };
            var builder = new StringBuilder ();
            using (Process process = Process.Start (startInfo)) {
                process.WaitForExit ();
                builder.Append (process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ());
            }
            return builder.ToString ();
        }

        public static int Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (MacUUID ());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
 "IOPlatformUUID" = "9E134619-9999-9999-9999-90DC147C61A9"
```

You could also parse out "IOPlatformSerialNumber" instead of the "IOPlatformUUID" if you want something human readable and that someone can find on the main dialog of "About This Mac" for tech support calls...

Now if you are looking at storing and protecting info as in the MS DPAPI, the KeyChain is the place to do that (OSX/iOS). Mono does have some of the DPAPI crypto apis that are x-plat based.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Im using Xamarin Studio.. i dont understand what is xamarin.mac.. isnt it mono itself. So this IOPlatformUUID  will be unique and will not change if the user changes the password or something.Also can you please tell me; which version of Mac added this.I don't want to unnecessary restrict app installation based on version.

Comment: I believe I/O Kit and drivers was totally formed in 10.4(?), but you would need to up it up in Apple's SDK to confirm that, but Mono supports OS-X 10.7+ so you would be fine using it. My understanding is that the platform ID is stable and locked to the logic board... XamMac is a C# library that binds the Mac interfaces and allows you to publish a native .app using native dialogs/windows/etc... on OS-X, it is an optional platform for Xamarin Studio just like iOS or Android are. Check pricing and licensing  on their site, but it starts at $25/month per dev just like the mobile platforms cost.

Comment: Thanks i will check with apple sdk.But since mono only supports 0SX versions after 10.7 http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/ it wont be a problem.Im using the same thing there is a free edition of xamarin.I design UI on GTK and write code in C#.You need to buy xamarin.mac if you need to create a package for distribution.

Comment: If you are just coding for GTK#/GTK2+ guis, then you can avoid XamMac unless you really need the native bindings that it offers and do not want to extend MonoMac with the APIs that you need access to.

Comment: My app just works fine on Mac now.The only thing i need now is the unique system id as i have told you and a way to pack my app and mono runtime as an installer package.I cannot afford Xamarin.mac now ,there are some guides online to do that manually.Hope it will work.Does your code above need Xamarin.mac ??

Comment: im sorry but i did not get what you said.Xamarin.mac is not required to the run the code example you have provided,right?

Comment: Correct, no Xamarin.Mac required for this.

Comment: Robert is there any way by which i can return only the system id  without "IOPlatformUUID" in it.

Comment: Try " ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice |  awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { print $3; }' " in the cmd line to see if I got that right (no double quotes, but do not miss the single ones... Or just string split it in C# on the equals symbol

Comment: @SushiHangover Does the value of IOPlatformUUID remain constant even after macOS update?