# How to get monitor EDID in OS X?

Tags: xamarin, pinvoke, iokit, xamarin.mac, edid

I'm looking to pull the EDID information in OS X / macOS?

It looks like it's stored in the `IORegistry`. Is there a way to access it with the current `monomac` libraries? Can I do it with standard `interop` or do I need to write a custom `shim`?

It looks like the `ioreg` command line can also get to `IODisplay` EDID attribute, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get an abbreviated list of devices.

Comment: `IOKit` has not been bound by Xamarin (low # of requests thus low priority)  (Tracking issue https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28503), While I have done a some bindings, I find it WAY faster to just do a shell and use `ioreg` and parse the info you need i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31716044/4984832

Comment: I grabbed this from another site awhile back (it pops up on multiple sites now via google) : `ioreg -lw0 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6` Should get you headed in the right way depending upon your end needs

Answer (score 9):

Sadly, there's no out-of-the box solution.

First, what you want to do is download the "edid-decode" program. Unfortunately, it's not available via homebrew so you'll have to download it from https://git.linuxtv.org/edid-decode.git/ or https://github.com/timvideos/edid-decode. Luckily, it's just a single .c file, so you only need to type "make". (Don't do "make install" without editing the bindir and mandir in the Makefile). Put the resulting binary in your path.

Then execute `ioreg -lw0 -r -c "IODisplayConnect" -d 2 | grep IODisplayEDID` (kudos to @Steven) to get the EDID data in hex form for all of your monitors.

Select one of your outputs, copy the hex string to the clipboard, and then execute `pbpaste | edid-decode`

Comment: Perfect - amazingly useful information.  A heads up to anyone worried about having to compile `edid-decode` - just download the repository as a zip, extract, enter the resulting directory in terminal and type 'make'.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Just adding on: you will need to have a compiler on your system. If not, install xcode first, or find a friend to compile it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler solution for recent macOSes:

```bash
system_profiler -json SPDisplaysDataType  | jq -r '.SPDisplaysDataType[0].spdisplays_ndrvs[]._spdisplays_edid'
```

That'll extract the EDID in hex format for monitors on the first GPU.  Change the index ("`[0]`") to `[1]` or `[2]`, etc, to get it for other GPUs/monitors.  Or just drop `jq` and copy+paste the hex EDID found in the detailed output:

```bash
system_profiler -json SPDisplaysDataType
```

The solutions that rely on `ioreg` all work, but parsing its output is a pain and could break in the future. Apple doesn't document it, but when `system_profiler` is used with the `-json` or `-xml` flags it outputs far more information. Including the edid which we care about.

note: the `-json` flag on `system_profiler` is relatively new. If you don't have the `-json` flag you can use `-xml` instead though then you can't use jq to parse the output: `system_profiler -xml SPDisplaysDataType`

Comment: `jq` isn't available by default, but homebrew has it. The first of those gives me `null, null`, and the JSON output in the second doesn't contain any `_spdisplays_edid` properties at all.

Comment: @Synchro My `[0]` index is probably wrong for you.  It depends on your GPU order and which monitor is using which GPU.  Though does `system_profiler -json SPDisplaysDataType | grep -i edid` just return nothing for you?  If so, is there anything peculiar about your monitor setup? I'm surprised you can't find an EDID in either `ioreg -l | grep  "IODisplayEDID"` or `system_profiler`!  You could also try `system_profiler -xml SPDisplaysDataType | grep -i -A1 _edid` to make sure that doesn't work.

Comment: It's a Mac Studio, so I only have one GPU, and it's definitely index 0. I've added the full output to my answer; as you can see, there is no EDID, but you can see that my monitors have duplicate serial numbers.

Comment: Interesting! Sorry I can't be of much help. Surprised it's not in this or `ioreg`. Maybe macOS just doesn't output EDID data for Apple GPUs or in certain situations. Like I notice on my output it seems to say it's using DisplayPort to talk to my MBP screen and that `spdisplays_vendor` is  `Intel`, whereas yours is `sppci_vendor_Apple` and no mention of DisplayPort for you.  Here's my output for comparison: https://gist.github.com/varenc/4df0789257c2c3e9cc18d5f8a1b1a445

Last suggestion: You could try SwitchResX (https://www.madrau.com/) and see if its "Export EDID" button works for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check EDID text, try

```
ioreg -lw0 -r -c "IODisplayConnect" -n "display0" -d 2 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would make this answer much more useful. Just throwing in a command line, that does not even answer the question (not only the question title) is hardly helping the OP. or someone else to gain some insight.

Comment: Annoyingly, I have three displays on my Mac, and all three of them are named "display0".

Answer (score 2):

```
for theedid in $(ioreg -lw0 -r -c "IODisplayConnect" -d 2 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed -E "/^.*<(.*)>/s//\1/"); do edid-decode <<< $theedid; done
```

anything that looks like edid:

```
for theedid in $(ioreg -lw0 | grep '<00ffffffffffff' | sed -E "/^.*<(.*)>/s//\1/"); do edid-decode <<< $theedid; done
```

or:

```
ioreg -lrw0 -c "IODisplayConnect" -d2 | sed -nE '/^.*"IODisplayEDID" = <(.*)>/s//edid-decode <<< \1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ioreg -l | grep IODisplayEDID
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Building on @KTane's answer, that snippet didn't show anything, but this does (macOS Monterey 12.3 on a Mac Studio):

```
ioreg -l | grep EDID
    | |   |   |   "DisplayAttributes" = {"SupportsSuspend"=No,"MaximumRefreshRate"=144,"SupportsActiveOff"=No,"PortID"=32,"ProductAttributes"={"ManufacturerID"="SAM","YearOfManufacture"=2018,"SerialNumber"=810889805,"ProductName"="C27JG5x","AlphanumericSerialNumber"="HTOKC02346","LegacyManufacturerID"=19501,"ProductID"=3928,"WeekOfManufacture"=51},"MaxVerticalImageSize"=34,"MaxHorizontalImageSize"=60,"HasHDMILegacyEDID"=No,"Chromaticity"={"Red"={"X"=44352,"Y"=20736},"Green"={"X"=18048,"Y"=43328},"Blue"={"X"=9984,"Y"=4032}},"DefaultColorSpaceIsSRGB"=No,"NativeFormatHorizontalPixels"=2560,"DefaultWhitePoint"={"X"=20544,"Y"=21568,"Gamma"=144179},"SupportsVariableRefreshRate"=No,"AspectRatio"=15,"MinimumRefreshRate"=50,"WhitePoints"=({"X"=20544,"Y"=21568,"Gamma"=144179}),"PreciseAspectRatio"=115652,"ContinuousFrequencySupport"="None","SupportsStandby"=Yes,"NativeFormatVerticalPixels"=1440}

    | |   |   |   "EDID UUID" = "4C2D580F-0000-0000-331C-0104A53C2278"

    | |   |   |   "DisplayAttributes" = {"SupportsSuspend"=No,"MaximumRefreshRate"=144,"SupportsActiveOff"=No,"PortID"=48,"ProductAttributes"={"ManufacturerID"="SAM","YearOfManufacture"=2018,"SerialNumber"=810889805,"ProductName"="C27JG5x","AlphanumericSerialNumber"="HTOKC02337","LegacyManufacturerID"=19501,"ProductID"=3928,"WeekOfManufacture"=51},"MaxVerticalImageSize"=34,"MaxHorizontalImageSize"=60,"HasHDMILegacyEDID"=No,"Chromaticity"={"Red"={"X"=44352,"Y"=20736},"Green"={"X"=18048,"Y"=43328},"Blue"={"X"=9984,"Y"=4032}},"DefaultColorSpaceIsSRGB"=No,"NativeFormatHorizontalPixels"=2560,"DefaultWhitePoint"={"X"=20544,"Y"=21568,"Gamma"=144179},"SupportsVariableRefreshRate"=No,"AspectRatio"=15,"MinimumRefreshRate"=50,"WhitePoints"=({"X"=20544,"Y"=21568,"Gamma"=144179}),"PreciseAspectRatio"=115652,"ContinuousFrequencySupport"="None","SupportsStandby"=Yes,"NativeFormatVerticalPixels"=1440}

    | |   |   |   "EDID UUID" = "4C2D580F-0000-0000-331C-0104A53C2278"
```

Can you spot the problem? Yes, both my monitors have the same serial number and UUID. Samsung needs a slap...

### Update:

Here's the full output of `system_profiler -json SPDisplaysDataType`:

```json
{
  "SPDisplaysDataType" : [
    {
      "_name" : "Apple M1 Max",
      "spdisplays_mtlgpufamilysupport" : "spdisplays_metal3",
      "spdisplays_ndrvs" : [
        {
          "_name" : "C27JG5x",
          "_spdisplays_display-product-id" : "f58",
          "_spdisplays_display-serial-number" : "3055324d",
          "_spdisplays_display-vendor-id" : "4c2d",
          "_spdisplays_display-week" : "51",
          "_spdisplays_display-year" : "2018",
          "_spdisplays_displayID" : "4",
          "_spdisplays_pixels" : "2560 x 1440",
          "_spdisplays_resolution" : "2560 x 1440 @ 144.00Hz",
          "spdisplays_main" : "spdisplays_yes",
          "spdisplays_mirror" : "spdisplays_off",
          "spdisplays_online" : "spdisplays_yes",
          "spdisplays_pixelresolution" : "spdisplays_qhd",
          "spdisplays_resolution" : "2560 x 1440 @ 144.00Hz",
          "spdisplays_rotation" : "spdisplays_supported"
        },
        {
          "_name" : "C27JG5x",
          "_spdisplays_display-product-id" : "f58",
          "_spdisplays_display-serial-number" : "3055324d",
          "_spdisplays_display-vendor-id" : "4c2d",
          "_spdisplays_display-week" : "51",
          "_spdisplays_display-year" : "2018",
          "_spdisplays_displayID" : "3",
          "_spdisplays_pixels" : "2560 x 1440",
          "_spdisplays_resolution" : "2560 x 1440 @ 144.00Hz",
          "spdisplays_mirror" : "spdisplays_off",
          "spdisplays_online" : "spdisplays_yes",
          "spdisplays_pixelresolution" : "spdisplays_qhd",
          "spdisplays_resolution" : "2560 x 1440 @ 144.00Hz",
          "spdisplays_rotation" : "spdisplays_supported"
        }
      ],
      "spdisplays_vendor" : "sppci_vendor_Apple",
      "sppci_bus" : "spdisplays_builtin",
      "sppci_cores" : "24",
      "sppci_device_type" : "spdisplays_gpu",
      "sppci_model" : "Apple M1 Max"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't include the actual EDID information in it. As in, there's nothing to parse with `edid-decoder`, etc.  That said, you can check if the solution I just posted works:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156493/how-to-get-monitor-edid-in-os-x/74523869#74523869  Apple might have changed something about `ioreg` which breaks the other solutions, but I can confirm mine works on 12.3.